# Rewrite rule for URL with multiple query parameters in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to be able to dynamically change the following URL type

`www.website.com/listings/?q=&rtcl_location=city-state&rtcl_category=category-type`

to look like

`www.website.com/city-state/category-type/`

I tried using [generateit.net/mod-rewrite/](Generate It's Mod Rewrite) but the only thing it changed was removing the q=%, the new URL looks like this:

`www.webiste.com/?rtcl_location=city-state&rtcl_category=category-type`

This is all latin to me and I appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

I tried reading multiple answers online and translate those answers to my own htaccess but have failed thus far.

I've also tried utilizing some generators online, as mentioned above, which have not given the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward, actually:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect /listings/?q=&rtcl_location=city-state&rtcl_category=category-type
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:^|&)rtcl_location=([^&]+)&rtcl_category=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?listings/?$ /%1/%2/ [QSD,L,R=301]

# Rewrite /city-state/category-type/
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /listings/?rtcl_location=$1&rtcl_category=$2 [L]
```

That covers both, redirecting requests to the "old" URL and internally rewriting requests to the "new" URL.

I dropped the "q" query arg, it does not have any meaning according to what you wrote.

It is a good idea to start with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection. And to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That precents nasy caching issues while testing. Nevertheless you should always test using a fresh anonymous browser window or clear or disable your browsers cache.